# failure of floating point interrupt MFC Windows 10

Tags: c++, mfc, floating-point, windows-10-desktop

We have an MFC product built in Visual Studio 2012/13 in C++ that performs many mathematical calculations.  We use floating point interrupts through the coprocessor to help speed up the calculations, by setting up try/catch blocks.  Those interrupts work well in Windows 7, but one of the updates for Windows 10 broke the sequence.  While the "signal" call still sets up the correct pointer for the "handler" callback,  Windows 10 ignores it.  (The same code works in a console program; it only fails in MFC code, even the simplest stripped example).  We have a workaround using SEH, but we would still like to know why this happened.  Thanks for any information.

The relevant code is, where the handler throws a FloatException (note that an interrupt never gets to the handler in Windows 10):

```
   _clearfp();
   _controlfp_s(0,  _EM_INEXACT, _MCW_EM);
   signal(SIGFPE, (fptr)HandleMathError);
   try
   {
     ...calculate
   }
   catch (FloatException &e)
   {
      ...recover
      _fpreset();
      _clearfp();
      _controlfp_s(0, old_control_word, _MCW_EM);
      signal(SIGFPE, SIG_DFL);
      return;
   }
```

For completeness, in order to see the MFC failure, the required code has at least 9 files or so.  First generate a simple MFC application using: single document, doc/view, mfc standard interface, static library, no compound doc, no database, classic menu.  Then, in the MainFrm::OnCreate, insert the interrupt code above with "raise(SIGFPE)" as the only calculation.  Add a definition for the "HandleMathError" and "Float Exception" as:

```
typedef void( *fptr )( int );

void __cdecl HandleMathError( int sig, int subcode );

class FloatException : public std::exception
{
public:
    FloatException( int _foo )
    {
        foo = _foo;
    }
    int foo;
};

void __cdecl HandleMathError( int sig, int subcode )
{
    throw FloatException( subcode );
    return;
}
```

With this code, the interrupt handler is entered on Windows 7, and is not entered in Windows 10.  A test for the handler being present using signal is positive on both OSs; Windows 10 is ignoring the handler.

Comment: *"it only fails in MFC code, even the simplest stripped example"* - Why don't you post a [mcve] then? It's also important to know your floating point compiler settings, as well as the target architecture. I haven't heard about code using interrupts and a coprocessor in more than 20 years. What setup are you using? (I'm sure this cannot possibly be a 80387, although that really is the only chip I know that goes by the term *coprocessor* and is programmed through *interrupts*.)

Comment: I use the following settings: /EHsc, ?fp:precise, /fp:except, and /arch:IA32.  the last switch forces the use of the embedded i87.  the code i use is 10-100 times faster than deeply embedded searches for NAN and INF.  The simplest MFC is as said, generate MFC, embed calc that "raise(SIGFPE)" and go.

Comment: I once had to diagnose a problem that was traced back to a device driver changing the FP flags and not restoring them... the bug would manifest only after printing to a HP printer. Not sure if that's even a possibility in more modern versions of Windows.

Comment: @MarkRansom, Thanks for the thought.  I have had this Windows 10 failure on three customer systems and two of my own, including a "clean" isolated system with nothing added.  That still leaves a lot of running services though.  Further, the return of an inserted "signal" just before a failure still points to the correct "handler".  I'll try to look at the control word again.